Iteration over rows and apply function based on condition
I am learning iteration and apply function in pandas. I have an example below. for every 4 rows apply a function (1st row + 0 , 2nd row + 0, 3rd row = 0, 4th row = 0) and so on. Any link resources to do this operation? Many Thanks.
data = {'DATE': ['2023-12-29', '2023-12-29', '2023-12-29', '2023-12-29','2024-01-31','2024-01-31','2024-01-31','2024-01-31',
                '2024-02-27','2024-02-27','2024-02-27','2024-02-27'],
        'score': [10, 5, 30, 41,12,7,32,43,14,9,34,45]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)


        DATE      Score Result
    0   2023-12-29  10  10
    1   2023-12-29  5   5
    2   2023-12-29  30  0   
    3   2023-12-29  41  0   
    4   2024-01-31  12  12
    5   2024-01-31  7   7
    6   2024-01-31  32  0   
    7   2024-01-31  43  0   
    8   2024-02-27  14  14
    9   2024-02-27  9   9   
    10  2024-02-27  34  0    
    11  2024-02-27  45  0


Code
cond = df.index.to_series().mod(4).isin([2, 3])
df['result'] = df['score'].mask(cond, 0)

df
          DATE  score  result
0   2023-12-29     10      10
1   2023-12-29      5       5
2   2023-12-29      8       0
3   2023-12-29      2       0
4   2023-12-29      7       7
5   2023-12-27     10      10
6   2023-12-27     12       0
7   2023-12-27      7       0
8   2023-12-27      9       9
9   2024-01-31     13      13
10  2024-02-27     14       0
11  2024-02-27      9       0


Update Answer for additional question
(1st row +5 , 2nd row +8, 3rd row = 0, 4th row -10)
s = pd.Series([5, 8, 0, -10])[df.index % 4].reset_index(drop=True)
df['result'] = df['score'] + s

df
          DATE  score  result
0   2023-12-29     10      15
1   2023-12-29      5      13
2   2023-12-29      8       8
3   2023-12-29      2      -8
4   2023-12-29      7      12
5   2023-12-27     10      18
6   2023-12-27     12      12
7   2023-12-27      7      -3
8   2023-12-27      9      14
9   2024-01-31     13      21
10  2024-02-27     14      14
11  2024-02-27      9      -1

It's easier to do indexing numpy array, but you might not know numpy, so I did indexing on a pandas series.

thanks Panda Kim for the answer, any example if the condition is (1st row +5 , 2nd row +8, 3rd row = 0, 4th row -10) ?

@stvlam22 i update my answer

Could you provide example using numpy ?, my main purpose actually is to apply function or condition (if condition) for each row within 4 rows, then apply the function for next 4 rows and so on. btw thanks for the answer

@stvlam22 I think you should choose answer and ask additional questions. The answer to the last additional question is to index the array with numpy instead of series in the answer above. If you don't know what indexing an array of numpy means, just use the code above.

Yes I understand Panda Kim, Thanks for your explanation. Really helpful

For an efficient approach, don't loop, craft numpy arrays with numpy.tile and add the values and multiply by 1/0 the rows you want to keep/reset:
import numpy as np

add = [5, 8, 0, -10] # value to add
mul = [1, 1, 0,   1] # values to reset (0 = reset)
n = int(np.ceil(len(df)/len(add))) # 3

df['Result'] = (df['score']
                .mul(np.tile(mul, n)[:len(df)])
                .add(np.tile(add, n)[:len(df)])
               )

NB. if the number of rows is always a multiple of the number of operation, you can use n = len(df)//len(add) and remove the [:len(df)].
n = len(df)//len(add) # 3

df['Result'] = df['score'].mul(np.tile(mul, n)).add(np.tile(add, n))

Output:
          DATE  score  Result
0   2023-12-29     10      15
1   2023-12-29      5      13
2   2023-12-29     30       0
3   2023-12-29     41      31
4   2024-01-31     12      17
5   2024-01-31      7      15
6   2024-01-31     32       0
7   2024-01-31     43      33
8   2024-02-27     14      19
9   2024-02-27      9      17
10  2024-02-27     34       0
11  2024-02-27     45      35

variant
If your groups are non regular, you could combine this with groupby.cumcount and numpy indexing:
add = np.array([5, 8, 0, -10])
mul = np.array([1, 1, 0,   1])
n = df.groupby('DATE').cumcount()
df['Result'] = df['score'].mul(mul[n]).add(add[n])

timings


Another efficient way to do, many thanks mozway.

@stvlam22 you're welcome. Note that the accepted answer doesn't really give the correct result.

Note it, Mozway, Thanks for the advice, learn a lot.

How does my numpy_select method compare after fixing my code to do df.index.to_series().mod(n) only once rather than 4 times? It would also be interesting to see how these scale with the number of conditions~

numpy.select may serve you well:
import numpy as np

n = 4
index_n = df.index.to_series().mod(n)
conditions = [
    index_n.eq(i)
    for i in range(n)
]
choices = [
    df.score.add(5),  # 1st row +5
    df.score.add(8),  # 2nd row +8
    0,                # 3rd row = 0
    df.score.sub(10), # 4th row -10
]

df["result"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

Output:
          DATE  score  result
0   2023-12-29     10      15
1   2023-12-29      5      13
2   2023-12-29     30       0
3   2023-12-29     41      31
4   2024-01-31     12      17
5   2024-01-31      7      15
6   2024-01-31     32       0
7   2024-01-31     43      33
8   2024-02-27     14      19
9   2024-02-27      9      17
10  2024-02-27     34       0
11  2024-02-27     45      35


Thanks for your answer BeRT2me, Really helpful, I will learn it

If each 4 rows is by column DATE is possible use GroupBy.transform with custom function:
def f(x):
    x.iat[0] += 5
    x.iat[1] += 8
    x.iat[2] = 0
    x.iat[3] -= 10
    return x

df['result'] = df.groupby('DATE')['score'].transform(f)
print (df)
          DATE  score  result
0   2023-12-29     10      15
1   2023-12-29      5      13
2   2023-12-29     30       0
3   2023-12-29     41      31
4   2024-01-31     12      17
5   2024-01-31      7      15
6   2024-01-31     32       0
7   2024-01-31     43      33
8   2024-02-27     14      19
9   2024-02-27      9      17
10  2024-02-27     34       0
11  2024-02-27     45      35

If each 4 rows is not by DATE column:
def f(x):
    x.iat[0] += 5
    x.iat[1] += 8
    x.iat[2] = 0
    x.iat[3] -= 10
    return x

df['result'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4)['score'].transform(f)

If possible some group has 1,2 or 3 rows one idea is skip this row, e.g. by try-except:
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data).drop(11)

def f(x):
    try:
        x.iat[0] += 5
        x.iat[1] += 8
        x.iat[2] = 0
        x.iat[3] -= 10
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return x

df['result'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4)['score'].transform(f)
print (df)
          DATE  score  result
0   2023-12-29     10      15
1   2023-12-29      5      13
2   2023-12-29     30       0
3   2023-12-29     41      31
4   2024-01-31     12      17
5   2024-01-31      7      15
6   2024-01-31     32       0
7   2024-01-31     43      33
8   2024-02-27     14      19
9   2024-02-27      9      17
10  2024-02-27     34       0


Many Thanks jezrael, detailed example, I will digest it.
